# Need Regular expression example

Tags: regex

I'm new to Regular expression.

Any one can give me an example of: ^[DR]\d{4}$

Thanks.

Comment: Any line that starts with either "D" or "R" followed by four digits and ends with a linebreak or end of stream. See previous comment for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^[DR]\d{4}$` means:

> ^ - beginning of the text
>
> [DR] - letter 'D' or 'R'
>
> \d - digit
>
> {4} - last pattern repeated 4 times
>
> $ - ending of the text

example: [R1234](http://regexr.com?33qcm)